# CentOS 8 логи авторизации

Tags: linux, логирование, centos8

Подскажите пожалуйста, где и как просмотрить логи кто/как/когда авторизовывался в CentOS8?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В журнале все есть для интерактывных входов

```
journalctl -u systemd-logind.service
```

Неудачные попытки можно найти по SYSLOG_FACILITY (аналог auth.log)

```
journalctl -l SYSLOG_FACILITY=10
```

Comment: journalctl -u systemd-logind.service Очень не информаутивный лог.... Не указано ни через чего зашли типа ssh, ни IP, ни попытки входа (ввод не правильного пароля), нет информации до ребута...

Comment: @Dikens добавил как вычитать auth.log

Comment: Этот журнал показывает логи только что было после ребута...  нашёл интересную утилиту last, которая показывает все сессии которые были..

Comment: Так включи сохранение логов mkdir /var/log/journal

Comment: А сохранение логов включается путём простого создание директории "journal" в /var/log/?

Comment: на дефолтных настройках журнала - да. там стоит персистент=авто